# Active record group by relation and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have these classes

```
class Challenge
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo
  belong_to :challenge
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote
  belongs_to :photo
end
```

I'm trying to get for every photo how many vote I have.
I try with

```
@challenge.photos.group_by(&:votes)
```

But the result is not what I need...

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy to fetch the votes count for each photo, you can introduce a new column in `:photos` names `:votes_count` and add `counter_cache: true` in the `belongs_to` association in the `Vote` model.

```
class Vote
  belongs_to :photo, counter_cache: true
end

class AddVotesCountToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :photos, :votes_count, :integer
  end
end
```

Now you can easily query the votes count for any photo:

```
@photo.votes_count
```

One way to find the votes for each photo for a particular challenge:

```
photos_with_votes = @challenge.photos.each_with_object([]) do |photo, arr|
  arr << [photo.id, photo.votes_count]
end
```

By the way, as your tables might already have been populated with records, you need to reset all the counter caches to their correct values using an SQL count query. We will use [`reset_counters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reset_counters) for the purpose:

```
Photo.pluck(:id).each { |id| Photo.reset_counters(id, :votes) }
```